# Ubuntu 22.04 not booting after install -dual boot windows 11

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I am trying to install ubuntu 22.04 alongside windows 11 so that I have dual boot. I followed this step by step guide completely:

https://medium.com/linuxforeveryone/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-and-dual-boot-alongside-windows-10-323a85271a73

Everything appears to install correctly but when I restart my pc from ubuntu and it instructs you to remove the media device and hit enter, once I do so it just boots windows 11. There is no option to select ubuntu as an operating system.

Based on google searches, I have gone into the BIOS settings when booting up in an attempt to move Ubuntu to the top of the priorities but it isn't listed, only windows is. I've also entered into the command prompt:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

and while this now gives me an option to choose my operating system when booting up, only windows 11 is available.

My disk partitions do not show ubuntu at all:
[disk management screenshot][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I0JE.png

I also checked my program files to make sure I didn't somehow install ubuntu inside of windows somehow and I have no ubuntu files.

All of this led me to believe maybe nothing actually installed despite a successful installation according to ubuntu so I inserted my live usb and tried again. But now when I go to choose my installation type, instead of seeing the option "Install alongside of Windows" I get the option "Erase ubuntu and reinstall". I have of course followed through and erased and then reinstalled ubuntu but nothing changes.

Further invetigation suggests there is a problem with the boot so I followed this guide for boot repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

and here are the results: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sdWyfwDZz5/

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If so new as to run Windows 11, you need at least 22.04 to have latest kernel & drivers. You also show Secure Boot on. Ubuntu will install with it on, but then you only boot with shimx64.efi, not grubx64.efi. And only can dual boot from UEFI menu, not from grub. Grub cannot chainload to Window with Secure boot on. You also show Windows hibernated. You probably need both Windows fast start up/hibernation off & turn off bitlocker. You may not need to change drives to AHCI as many instructions (including my previous comments) as with NVMe Ubuntu uses vmd driver & just works.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I incorrectly said the version was 20.01. I am using version 22.04. In addition, I have disabled secure boot, turned off hibernation/ fast start up, turned off bitlocker and still no luck.

Comment: It looks like your Windows has some sort of RAID setup. I am not sure whether that is the cause of your problem. It looks like Ubuntu is installed in `nvme0n1p5` according to the Boot-Repair log in pastebin. Another possibility is Ubuntu was somehow installed in Legacy BIOS mode, while Windows is installed in UEFI mode. However, I don't see any sign of that in the Boot-Repair log.

Comment: Your report shows Secure Boot enabled, as it must be for Windows 11. If disabled Windows 11 won't boot.

Comment: To see if your Ubuntu install is actually there, boot into your live USB and open your partition manager (search apps for "partition" and open whichever comes up). This is the Linux version of Disk Management. It might not say "Ubuntu," but if your Ubuntu partition is, say, 100GB and it shows 20GB used, you'll know Ubuntu is there. As for your issue, I can't remember the details but when I installed Ubuntu (using the "manual" installation option) I was asked which partition I wanted to boot from or something similar. I believe I chose the partition labeled "ESP" and flagged as "boot, esp."